# ArrayAdapter changed for a ListView but onClickListener doesn't know

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have 1 ListView and two ArrayAdapters

Depending on an if statement, this will happen

`listView1.setAdapter(adapter1);`
or
`listView1.setAdapter(adapter2);`

On onCreate(), this is called,
`listView1.setAdapter(adapter1);`

So listView1.setOnItemClickListener() is connected to adapter 1.

During program execution when `listView1.setAdapter(adapter2);` is called, the ListView is updated and the display shows the appropriate results, however, clicking an item with  the adapter2 results is actually still referencing the adapter1 results.

How do I get the onItemClickListener to switch when listView1's adapters change?

Thanks

```
        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            Intent i = new Intent("com.project.DetailView");
            i.putExtra("serial", list.get(position).getSerial());
            i.putExtra("name", list.get(position).getName());

            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}


adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list1);

adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list2);
```

Comment: Please show code of your onItemClick method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code may help u.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("item",""+listView.getItemAtPosition(position));

            }
        });
```

Comment: This is interesting, because this code shows the correct item being picked in LogCat.

Answer (score 1):

Code in onItemClick, dont have any dependency on Adapters, it has dependency over list.
I think you should override `getItem` method of both these two adapters, and instead of getting item by list, `getItem` from Adapter, If you return a HashMap from the `getItem(int position)`, then you should modify your method to following:

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            HashMap<String, String> item=getAdapter().getItem(position);

            Intent i = new Intent("com.project.DetailView");
            i.putExtra("serial", item.get("serial"));
            i.putExtra("name", item.get("name"));

            startActivity(i);

        }
```

Comment: I don't think getItem is overrideable for my class.

Comment: getItem is overrideable by any adapter class, show your code of adapter

Answer (score 0):

When you set the adapter do this,

adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

OR

adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();

Still if it is not working post your code to know what exactly you have done.

Comment: Hello friend,this is only required when the data in the Adapter is Changed..I mean if you delete one of the Row from the Adapter,then you have to notify that.But here the case is Different,Whole Adapter is changed,not the Data.